# How can I manipulate through rxjs operators an object that i get from a request?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

My question is:
How can i manipulate an object in an object list that i get from http request. For example, i receive a list of objects with every object like

```
{
    start:start,
    end:end,
    title:title,
}
```

i need to modify to

```
{
    start: new Date(start),
    end: new Date(end),
    title:title,
    draggable:true,
    resizable:true,
}
```

my code

```
this.http.get('https:url-to-guest-events').pipe(
    //what operator can i use, map maybe?
)
.subscribe(
    events => this.events = events;
)
```

Comment: I assume `title, title:` is a typo and it should be `title: title,`...

Comment: yes friend, I have corrected it

Comment: The operator you are searching for is called map.

Answer (score 1):

The [`map` operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) is for converting/changing the data in the stream.

```
.pipe(
  map( original => {
    // code here to modify the original
    // be sure to call return on the result
  })
)
```

The absolute simplest transform you could do would probably be:

```
.pipe(
  map( original => {
    return {
      start: original.start,
      end: original.end,
      title: original.title,
      draggable: true,
      resizable: true
    }
  })
)
```

I personally would have declared a class and just set the values, but if you're just using freeform objects/hashes, this would suffice.

Here's a demo on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-3mdpjo?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100

Comment: Thanks your help my friend, your answer was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Use the `map` operator together with object deconstructing for the shortest result:

```
this.http.get('https:url-to-guest-events').pipe(
    map(({start, end, title}) => ({
        start: new Date(start),
        end: new Date(end),
        title: title,
        draggable: true,
        resizable: true,
    }))
)
.subscribe(
    events => this.events = events
)
```

In case you receive an array from your HTTP endpoint (which can be assumed due to the naming `events`) I'd suggest the use of `mergeMap` and `toArray` to perform mappings on each item and then collect the results, like this:

```
this.http.get('https:url-to-guest-events').pipe(
    mergeMap(result => result),
    map(({start, end, title}) => ({
        start: new Date(start),
        end: new Date(end),
        title: title,
        draggable: true,
        resizable: true,
    })),
    toArray()
)
.subscribe(
    events => this.events = events
)
```

`mergeMap` will stream all array items into individual notifications. After the mapping, `toArray` will collect all notifcations and put them back in an array, convenient for you to assign later in your `subscribe` function.

Comment: Thanks for you help, friend, It was solved my question.